# Old English weak noun 'Sweora'

Tags: historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, diphthongs

I've been reading about diphthongization and i umlaut of diphthongs and I came across the example of the OE word for 'neck'.

I have been led to understand that:

- the original vowel is 'i'.
- -rh- followed this vowel in the older Germanic.
- breaking of -i- before -rh- plus 'i/j' is not probable in Anglian (but it breaks to 'io' in West Saxon).
- This -h- is lost and causes compensatory lengthening of the vowel/diphthong.
- i umlaut of (long) io< (long) i causes West Saxon forms to be spelled 'swiera' (with long diphthong).

Under this reasoning any non West Saxon forms would only have (long) i in the form swira.

However, sweora/sweoran is attested quite a lot, and I have found swiora in an Exeter book riddle as well. Knowing that io does fall together with eo, these forms seem to indicate that there were instances when i was diphthongized to io.

That confuses me now that textbook sources have indicated very limited breaking of i.

So has there indeed been breaking, could there have been some sort of analogical leveling, or is this a case of scribal mistakes or practice?

Can someone shed light on this and provide another example if possible? Any help would be much appreciated; I'm just a layman wanting to know more out of interest.

Sources used:

*The Development of Old English* (Ringe and Taylor)

*A Comparative Grammar of the Early Germanic Languages* (Fulk)

Comment: This is not a word I’ve ever looked into, but Wiktionary traces _swēora_ and _swīera_ to different forms: _swēora_ from an underived PGmc. _*swerhō_ (with _e_ as the base vowel), and _swīera_ from a PGmc. _*-jō_ derivation that Wiktionary writes _*swirhijō_ (though most likely the _i_-umlaut postdates PGmc. proper, so more precisely that form should probably be labelled WGmc. instead of PGmc.). The non-derived form _*swerhō_ should, as far as I can think offhand, yield OE _ēo_ fairly straightforwardly, shouldn’t it?